# iOS sqlite data from SQL server

Tags: sql, ios, json, web-services, sqlite

I need to get large data (~100MB) from sql server into app's sqlite once a day wirelessly.

App has json/restful webservice for other things, but figured this isn't possible as 100MB loaded into memory via json object would cause memory crash when I try to write json to sqlite.

I am now considering retrieving a file from url and saving it locally.  That way data isn't loaded into memory.

The part I get fuzzy on is best way to get data, ie download a .sqlite compressed file or download a text file with prepared insert statements to an existing sqlite.  Pretty sure the prior is best choice, but not DB savy enough to know what's possible on the sql server.  Is it possible for a sql server to select data subsets and create a sqlite file?  maybe it just needs to be scripted.

One thing to consider is the structrue of data on the sql server.  I need subsets of data from several tables, not the entire tables.  Example:  SQL server houses 100 physical sites data, app is at site X today, just load site X data.

Am I on the right track or did a I miss an obvious solution?

Comment: 100MB daily??? Users will never use such application.

Comment: @YaqubAhmad It could very well be an enterprise application. I could easily see, say, a Utility Tech who needs his order database on his iPad refreshed every day.

Comment: right, this is an enterprise app for a specific customer of mine.  workers come on shift and sync app and put in 8 hours.  They need correct data for the day, but doing real time web service calls to get data would make app behave like a slow web page cause calls would be so frequent.

Comment: @Augie . . . Hmmm, you can probably design the app for the web service calls more easily than you can manage downloading 100 Mbytes/day to a multitude of users -- and then have the data be out-of-date within minutes after it is downloaded.